# Data entity filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, entity-framework

I have a method where I retrieve data from database and send it . But i  need to filter it.
I have below code:

```
using ESM_DASHBOARD.Data;
using ESM_DASHBOARD.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ESM_DASHBOARD.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class wareh_KPI_INController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly EsmDashboardContext _esmDashboardContext;
        public wareh_KPI_INController(EsmDashboardContext esmDashboardContext)
        {
            _esmDashboardContext = esmDashboardContext;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<wareh_KPI_IN> Get ()
        {
            return _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN;
        }
        [HttpGet("{Week_nb}")]
        public wareh_KPI_IN Get(int Week_nb)
        {

           return _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.Where(s => s.Week_nb == Week_nb);
        }
    }
}
```

but it diplay error (cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.iorderedenumerable to data.entities.

when i add `.FirstOrDefault()`
i return only 1 value

Comment: *"i return only 1 value"* - Is that not the intent?  The method specifically indicates that it should return only one record, not a collection of records.  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @David, how , i have a lot of rows with the same week_nb , im trying to return all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it diplay error (cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.iorderedenumerable to data.entities.
> when i add .FirstOrDefault() i return only 1 value

Because that's exactly what you're telling the code to do.  Take a look at the method where you return all of the records:

```
public IEnumerable<wareh_KPI_IN> Get ()
{
    return _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN;
}
```

What does this method return?  An `IEnumerable<wareh_KPI_IN>`.  A *collection* of records.  Now take a look at the method with the error:

```
public wareh_KPI_IN Get(int Week_nb)
{
    return _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.Where(s => s.Week_nb == Week_nb);
}
```

What does it return?  A `wareh_KPI_IN`.  *One* record.

If you want to return a collection of records, return a collection of records:

```
public IEnumerable<wareh_KPI_IN> Get(int Week_nb)
{
    return _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.Where(s => s.Week_nb == Week_nb);
}
```

Exactly like *you already do* in your other method.